# Unhandled 'error' event when trowing error

Tags: node.js, koa

I have the following function for creating an user in my app,  I'm trying to detect if threre's already an admin user created and prevent for creating another one.

```
export async function createUser (ctx) {
  if ( ctx.request.body.type == undefined  ) {
      ctx.throw(400, 'Bad Request')
  }
  if (ctx.request.body.type === 'admin') {
    User.findOne({type:'admin'}, (err, usr) => {
      if (err)
        ctx.throw(422, err.message)
      if (usr){
        ctx.throw(400, 'Duplicate Admin')
      }
    })
  }
....
```

The first `ctx.throw(400, 'Bad Request')` works, but if another admin user is found the `ctx.throw(400, 'Duplicate Admin')` will cause the following error, crashing the app:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

BadRequestError: Duplicate Admin
```

I'm throwing the error in an inadequate manner? what causes the first throw to work without crashing but not the second?

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're throwing asynchronously inside the `User.findOne` callback. This crashes.

Instead, look at the library you're using that gives you `User.findOne` and see if it can return a promise, or wrap it in bluebird's `Promise.promisify` if it doesn't.

This is the code you want to arrive at:

```
const user = await User.findOne({ type: 'admin' }) // returns a promise
if (user) ctx.throw(400, 'Duplicate admin')
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, check the type of 'user' variable.If it an array or object, `if(user){....}`  will always return true, even if it's empty. And try to add

```
app.on('error', function() {
  console.log('yep this is an error');
});
```

event listener